# проблема apt-get install python3

Tags: cmd, apt-get, apt

Вот ошибка

```
>>> apt-get install python3
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    apt-get install python3
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Очевидно, это не является корректной синтаксической конструкцией в питоне, и здесь написана бессмыслица.

Comment: Поясню: это команда интерпртатора Shell, а вовсе не интерпретатора Python. И вводить её надо в консоли, в ответ на промт Shell.